# Maven (m2e) is not executing ant task

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, m2e

I have a POM file (to be executed by Eclipse) where I want to execute a ANT task during the `generate-sources` phase. Based on [m2e documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html), in [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin), [Maven: execute antrun task during package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960256/maven-execute-antrun-task-during-package) and [Where should be placed maven-compiler-plugin declaration: in <plugins> or <pluginManagement>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959358/where-should-be-placed-maven-compiler-plugin-declaration-in-plugins-or-plugi), I wrote my POM file in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project>

    ...

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                ...
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.8,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Plugin 1 -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Plugin to be executed during generate-sources phase. -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Should be in the generate-sources phase after the plugin above. -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ant-test</id>
                        <configuration>

                            <task>
                                <echo message="ANT TEST" />
                            </task>

                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    ...

</project>
```

What I understood from my reading, is that I am asking telling to Maven the following: *First ask to Eclipse plugin for Maven (m2e) to allow the maven-antrun-plugin (version 1.8 or above) to be executed during `generate-sources`. Next, in the `generate-sources` phase and after the execution of the first plugin, call the ant plugin to run the task which echo my message*.

However, the messagem is not being showed. Neither when I execute just the `generate-sources` goal nor when I execute the `install` goal.

I if follow [this sugestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7412569/1659543), and add the `<phase>` element inside `<execution>`, like here:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>ant-test</id>
        *<phase>generate-sources</phase>*
        <configuration>

            <task>
                <echo message="ANT TEST" />
            </task>

        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I have a Eclipse error message: *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (execution: ant-test, phase: generate-sources)*. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2623854/1659543) shows a example where there is no a specific `<pluginManagement>` for ant plugin. But also I had no success.

So What is missing here?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Comment: Change the configuration in m2e from `generate-sources` to `run`...

Comment: Sorry, it did not worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I discovered that the error message *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (execution: ant-test, phase: generate-sources)* has no effect in the Maven execution. The message is shown with no problems. To speak the truth, I had to change the `task` to `target`, but the message continues to be displayed. May be it is just a kind m2e's bug which the only effect is annoys us.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did the structure below, and it worked:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                ....
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-antrun-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.8,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
</build>
```